# addEventListener("beforeload") missing events

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a simple Chrome Addon to remove every event from domain x. I've looked into it and found out about the "beforeload" event listener, this is apparently what things like adblock use to block ads completely from loading. I've implemented this into the addon and added things like console.log("addon loaded") to be sure it's actually loading the javascript, but the **problem is, it only catches a handful of the events, for instance on a page of 50 events, it catches only maybe 1-2. It misses obvious other things.**

twitch.js

```
document.addEventListener("beforeload", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(event.target).remove();
}, true);
```

manifest.json

```
...
"content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "js/jquery.js", "js/twitch.js" ],
    "css": [ "css/twitch.css"],
    "matches": ["*://*/*"], 
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames" : true
}],
...
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

`beforeload` is called once for each script, iframe, image and stylesheet on the page, not for every event (do you mean element?). Were you expecting other elements to raise this event?

This document, [Blocking Unwanted Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/SafariExtensionGuide.pdf#page=88), mentions a requirement:

> To block content, your script must be run as a Start Script, so that it executes before the content is displayed.

So check that. Also, you don't need the `.remove()` line, just calling `event.preventDefault()` will stop the creation of the resource.

```js
document.addEventListener( 'beforeload', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, true );
```

Comment: Although this does help me realize more how addEventListener works, my code is more to emulate how an adblocker works, by getting a blacklist, and then checking it to make sure it's not there. If it is, to NOT load it and to remove it's element.

Comment: @clone1018 So when the page first loads, you want to remove any element on a blacklist, correct?

Comment: Yes, but not just by hiding the element, it has to NOT load the contents of the included resource into the page.

Comment: @clone1018 I added a link to a document with some things to try.